# Realm Swift Filter in Multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm, nspredicate

I have 10 separate viewcontrollers, where each needs to have their own unique filtered dataset. The object and its properties are the same for each controller but what appears in the collection view is based on what the user posts in that particular controller. Simply put, each planet needs to have their own data. Do I need 10 separate models? Or can I achieve this with Realm sorting by planet name and filtering with NSPredicate? My code below is crashing when the view loads.

```
class Planet: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var council = ""
  dynamic var capitol = ""
  dynamic var isAlive = false
  dynamic var arrived = Date()
}

class firstVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  let realm = try! Realm()
  var planets : Results<Planet>!
  let planet = Planet()

  override fun viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: false)

  planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).filter("name == firstPlanet", "")

  }


  // Delegate Methods

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return planets.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FirstVC

    cell.awakeFromNib()
    return cell
    }
  }
```

I have a custom cell class `PlanetCell` where the views are stored, hence, `cell.awakeFromNib`.

Comment: can you give us crash message?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 10 separate models... You just need create 10 object of `plant`class . 

But the problem of crash we need more informations , can you show the crash message ?

Comment: Hi Kira, by "10 object of plant (planet class?) class", do you mean 10 planet properties in my `Planet: Object` class? Such as `dynamic var planetOne`, `dynamic var planetTwo`, etc.?

Comment: @David Hey man, thanks for the cascading sorting and filtering. Sorry, first time working with `NSPredicate`, did not you could do that. Much cleaner! I'm assuming by *actual name of the planet and not a variable name* you also mean a property of my `Planet: Object` class, e.g. `dynamic var planetOne = ""`, etc.

Comment: The implicitly unwrapped optional is because when the app loads a fresh realm I have starter data that populates the cell with properties (buttons, image views and labels) but no data or current date. This doesn't crash the app. I can delete this initial empty cell and said properties after launch. Thread Exception only occurs when filtering specifically which planet and its data I should populate.

Comment: Disregard the last comment: the starter data in the AppDelegate loads the buttons, labels, etc. in the `FirstPlanetViewController` and I can post new data to `FirstPlanetViewController`'s view. But the `SecondPlanetViewController` comes up blank! This is how I am doing it: `let secondPlanet = "secondPlanet"` and in `viewDidLoad()` I have `planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).filter("name == %@", secondPlanet).sorted(byKeyPath: "capitol", ascending: false)`.

Comment: Then `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return planets.filter("name == %@", secondPlanet).count
  }` Help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the definition of planets and your filtering. Why would you define planets as implicitly unwrapped optional unless you are 100% sure you will have date that matches your NSPredicate when you populate planets?

Also, your NSPredicate syntax seems to be wrong, it should look like this assuming firstPlanet is the actual name of the planet and not a variable name: `planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).filter("name == 'firstPlanet'")`. If it is a variable name, it should look like this: `planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).filter("name == %@", firstPlanet)`.

You can also cascade sorting and filtering, you don't need to do it in two separate lines, like this: `planets = realm.objects(Planet.self).filter("name == 'firstPlanet'").sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: false)`.